# TestNG jar package test errors not detected by CI/CD pipeline

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, testng, pipeline

I'm running several TestNG tests in a project with Maven, but instead of executing mvn install or mvn test, I'm generating a jar file with dependencies. When I run it from GitLab CI/CD pipeline, if I run it with mvn and the test fails, the error is detected and the stage fails, but if I run it from the jar, the stage succeeds. Is there any way to detect the failure with the jar or is it the common behavior for jar executions?

Comment: Please give more details plus an example how a test is being executed etc... because I suppose you are doing things wrong...

Comment: It's pretty literal. I have a .gitlab-ci.yml where if i run the script with maven using the 'mvn test' command, the pipeline detects if the test fails and the stage throws an error, which is the expected behavior. What I'm currently doing is compiling the project with dependencies and running it with 'java -jar ./target/test-jar-with-dependencies.jar', which, for some reason, makes the stage succeed even if the test fails

Comment: `'mvn test' command, the pipeline detects if the test fails and the stage throws an error, which is the expected behavior. ` ? Why? Than your tests are broken.. That means you have to fix either your test code or your application code...

Comment: The tests are correct, I'm forcing them to fail and they fail indeed, the question aims to ask why GitLab runner is ignoring the result when the tests are packaged

Comment: First because your setup is wrong. By default (convention) a unit test is executed via Maven and can be detected..furthermore without the gitlab ci scripts it's impossible to even guess something..